# 429 Too many requests

Tags: polkadot

During high load, HTTP requests to the node start failing with the error:

> "429 Too many requests: Too many connections. Please try again later."

This same error is also displayed in the node's logs (screenshot).
Is there a way to increase the number of simultaneously open connections, similar to using the `'--ws-max-connections'` flag for websockets?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue discussed and closed here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/7039